# Is the relative inferior support of NVIDIA/Intel dual graphics on Linux compared to Windows more of a technical issue or licensing issue?

Tags: nvidia, hybrid-graphics

I have been using Linux desktop since 2014 and now (2020) it seems that the official support of NVIDIA/Intel dual graphics on Linux is still relative weak compared to Windows (please correct me if I am wrong). On Ubuntu there is a `prime-select` package that switches the graphics card (which still requires restart the session), but on some other distros this package does not even exist. Prime-synchronization also needs manual setup and sometimes breaks the GUI system.

Is there a real fundamental technical problem that prevents seamless graphics switching on Linux desktop, or is it just a licensing issue that prevents some techniques from being deployed, and prevents both sides from being happy and making money?

Comment: This question should be addressed to nVidia. I can admit, there is quite diference between nVidia and AMD support now, but it should be emphasized, that both these GPU vendor frendly behavior varies in time.

Answer (score 0):

Without any official statement from NVIDIA, we can only make assumptions. I assume, it is a simple business decision. Looking at the average end-user household which these Laptops may be found in, Linux market share is very low – [around 2%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems#Desktop_and_laptop_computers). If you look at those who do 3D gaming, it is even lower – [not even 1%](https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey). If I was making decisions at NVIDIA, I would not dedicate much resources to a relatively small amount of customers.

That said, the Linux support of NVIDIA products *themselves* is really good. Much more than one would expect in regard to the relatively low market share. This is because NVIDIA also sells a range of specialized computing equipment, which is technically quite similar to their graphics cards. The customers are not the typical end-users, though. They can be expected to be super-users. They know enough of the technical background to accept the inconveniences and are happy to have support at all. I assume most have a static setup and do not really need dual graphics. I suspect NVIDIA has done surveys.

Another point is that Xorg, or rather the predecessor it was based on (XFree86) itself is ancient: It was introduced in 1991. The presentation API is pretty much decoupled from the driver architecture. Most current features like support for recent technologies like Vulkan are available with the help of extensions, but the original concept is still in place.

In Windows on the other hand, the presentation is coupled relatively closely with the driver architecture. With [VxD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VxD), [WDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Model), and [WDDM](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Display_Driver_Model) Microsoft decided to overhaul their architecture three times within the same time-frame. With changes like those, you lose compatibility with existing divers, but it also gives the opportunity to implement completely new, previously impossible features like switching graphics.

This statement is only true for the "backend" or "driver" – the "frontend" stayed mostly the same or backwards compatible in both.

Comment: Regarding your first point, there are other sectors where it is interesting for NVIDIA to dedicate resources for Linux support (*e.g.* HPC, with CUDA, and rendering farms), but none of those sectors care about hybrid support. The X angle is a significant technical barrier here.